# Proper way to create a collection list view in Backbone

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I'm currently learning Backbone.js and I'm having a hard time learning how to properly use Views (since I have experienced when it comes to MVC), so here is what I'm trying to do:

**templates**:

```
    <script type="text/template" id="todolist-template">
        <ul></ul>
    </script>
    <script type="text/template" id="todo-template">
        <li>
            <%= item.name %>
            <%= item.description %>
            <%= item.priority %>
        </li>
    </script>
```

**html**:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

**Views**:

```
var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    className: 'todo',
    initialize: function() {
        this.template = _.template($('#todo-template').html());
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template({item: this.model}));
        return this;
    }
});

var TodoListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#container',
    tagName: 'ul',
    className: 'todolist',
    initialize: function() {
        this.template = _.template($('#todolist-template').html());
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        that = this;
        this.$el.empty();
        this.$el.append(this.template());
        this.collection.each(function(model) {
            that.$el.append(new TodoView({model: model.toJSON()}));
        });
        return this;
    }
});
```

**Models and Collections**:

```
var Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults : {
        name : '',
        priority: '',
        description: ''
    }
});

var TodoList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Todo
});

var todoList = new app.TodoList([
    new Todo({
        name: 'unclog the sink',
        priority: '10',
        description: 'FIX THE SINK!!!'
    }),
    new Todo({
        name: 'get bread',
        priority: '0',
        description: 'We are out of bread, go get some'
    }),
    new Todo({
        name: 'get milk',
        priority: '2',
        description: 'We are out of milk, go get some'
    })
]);
```

**"misc"**:

```
$(function() {
    new HeaderView();
    new TodoListView({collection: todoList});
    router = new AppRouter();
    Backbone.history.start();
});
```

What I'm trying to do is to create a `ul` which will then get populated with `li`s that contain the collection's data. I've been trying to fix/debug this code for a while now (at least 3 hours) but I'm constantly hitting errors or wrong results, so please someone explain to me the proper way of implementing this.

**edit (resulting HTML)**:

```
<div id="container">
    <ul></ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least one problem lies here:

```
that.$el.append(new TodoView({model: model.toJSON()}));
```

Should be

```
that.$el.append(new TodoView({model: model.toJSON()}).render().el);
```

Since you can't append a view to $el, but rather you should be appending the rendered html

Comment: Yep this works but unfortunately the `li` elements are created at same level as the `ul`.

Comment: Also, when you get comfortable with Backbone I would highly recommend [Marionette.js](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette) if you are going to any large scale Backbone development.

Comment: Follow what orange said as well, since the structure of your DOM won't be correct with what you have.

Comment: Also, somehow the `ul` doesn't get the className "todoList"

Comment: I'll make you a fiddle

Comment: I think i've fixed that by using `that.$el.find('ul').append(new TodoView({model: model.toJSON()}).render().el);`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `<li>` in your template as your view already wraps the template in those tags. If it still doesn't work, check the DOM and post it here. Same goes for `<ul>`...

Also, I don't see where you add your ListView to the DOM. `render` only operates on a local element which isn't part of the DOM yet. Once rendered, you have to add it to the DOM.

Comment: Shouldn't this generate the `ul`'s HTML and put it in the DOM? this.$el.append(this.template());
Thanks for the `li` information, I've fixed that but now the `li`s are created outside the `ul` (which somehow doesn't get the className `todoList` either).

Comment: `this.$el.append(this.template());` will not actually add it to the DOM (it will only append the template to its `$el` which isn't part of the DOM yet). Outside of this, you have to do something like this `$('body').html(todoList.render().el)`.